# Js: Function to detect field on signup form and fill it

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm programming a chrome extension and I need to autofill form an the current visited site. I find the code of the Bitwarden autofill scrut but I'm novice so I don't know how to implement it to my code. Also, the variables that have to complete the fields are in the script.js, and idk were the autofill should be.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your `script.js`:

```js
function getPasswordInput() {
    return document.querySelector('form input[type="password"]')
}

function getFormElement() {
    var passwordInput = getPasswordInput()
    while (!(passwordInput instanceof HTMLFormElement)) {
        passwordInput = passwordInput.parentElement
    }
    return passwordInput
}

function getUsernameInput() {
    return getFormElement().querySelector('input[type="text"]')
}

if (getPasswordInput()) {
    getUsernameInput().value = 'YOUR_USERNAME'
    getPasswordInput().value = 'YOUR_PASSWORD'
}
```

This code checks if there are any input elements on the site which have the type password. If so it will autofill the form. You just need to replace `YOUR_USERNAME` and `YOUR_PASSWORD` with the username and password.